# Does the method Array.Copy in the Array class change the size of an array in C#?

Tags: c#, methods, arrays

From my understanding this line of Code

```
Array.Copy(intArray, intArray2, intArray.Length);
```

Both copies the elements of intArray into intArray2 and specifies the length of the Destination Array. However, It could also mean that intArray.Length as the last parameter specifies the range of indexes to copy to.

For example:

```
using System;
public class myClass{
    public static void Main(){

        int[] intArray = new int[] {1,2};
        int[] intArray2 = new int[intArray.Length + 1];
        Array.Copy(intArray, intArray2, intArray.Length);
        intArray = intArray2;
        foreach(int i in intArray){
            Console.Write(intArray[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

why does this print out 201?

Comment: C# != C++ != C - don't say "C based languages" - they behave differently.

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/78846/the-definition-of-c-based-language                                            ...  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_C-based_programming_languages

Comment: Those are all languages that have C style syntax - they are not based on C (C# is managed - no direct memory management, for instance).

Comment: and each of the C-based languages define arrays differently this is just a question about C#

Comment: Just because Memory direct memory management is not forced does not make it Non C-Based. If thats the case then you can Say Objective-C is not a C-Based language, since you can take turn on autoReferencing i.e Garabage collector. So yea I believe you are wrong.

Comment: your code will just generate a ArgumentExeption see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa310862%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Comment: http://ideone.com/exv0e8 copy and paste the code here

Comment: And no it doesn't throw and Argument Exception, This is  a sample code that is being deployed in an enterprise application. Im Just trying to see why this works. Im not looking for an argument.

Comment: If this snippet of code is in a deployed enterprise application, you have yourself a submission for [The Daily Wtf](http://thedailywtf.com/), and might need to take a close look at the code your engineers are putting in this app...

Comment: @KquaneIngram Both of your citations specifically mentioned C based being a syntax related definition. Objective-C is a strict superset of C but it's unique in being so among the C "family".

Comment: This is exactly why I on here asking questiong  @JimmyHoffa

Comment: One of the issues with your question is that it refers to array size, but at absolutely no point in your code do you actually look at the size of the array; so array size has nothing to do with this, is your question more of a "What is this code doing?"

Comment: @JimmyHoffa `int[] intArray2 = new int[intArray.Length + 1];` I believe that is the part of the question looking at the size of the array.

Comment: @Mike That part aswell as Array.Copy(intArray, intArray2, intArray.Length);    With this method, I was thought that the last argument specified the Length/SIZE of the Desitination array.

Comment: Read the manual: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.copy.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't change the size of the array. Look at what you are doing.

This initialises a new array with a Length or 2. Creating the array

```
int[] intArray = new int[] {1,2};
int[0] = 1
int[1] = 2
```

This line creates a new array of length 3

```
int[] intArray2 = new int[intArray.Length + 1];
```

intArray.Length returns 2, then you add 1 to it. Making intArray2 3 in length.

By default all int array values are set to 0 in intArray2.

i.e.

```
intArray2[0] = 0 
intArray2[1] = 0 
intArray2[2] = 0
```

You Copy function is copying the values from intArray to intArray2
making

```
intArray2[0] = 1
intArray2[1] = 2 
intArray2[2] = 0
```

the line

```
intArray = intArray2
```

doesn't copy the values back to intArray. It points intArray to the address of intArray2.

The way your foreach loop is written causes the array to be printed as:

```
intArray[1] = 2
intArray[2] = 0
intArray[0] = 1
```

It should be written as

```
foreach(int i in intArray)
{
    Console.Write(i);
}
```

**Update**

> From my understanding this line of Code
>
> Array.Copy(intArray, intArray2, intArray.Length);
>
> Both copies the elements of intArray into intArray2 and specifies the length of the Destination Array. However, It could also mean that intArray.Length as the last parameter specifies the range of indexes to copy to.

In both these statements you are not quite correct.

The [Array.Copy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k4yx47a1.aspx) method parameters, in particular the last one you refer to, is the number of elements to copy from the origin array. It won't specify the length of the destination array. Your use of the word range, isn't quite correct either. That would be (IMHO)

```
Array.Copy(intArray, intArray2, startIndex, endIndex);
```

which I don't think exists in the .NET Framework.

Comment: oh I didn't even see that index abuse there, that's why it prints 201 instead of 120... man that little snippet is a spectacular specimen

Comment: foreach(int i in intArray)
{
    Console.Write(intArray);
}  This prints out System.Int32[]System.Int32[]System.Int32[]